# Calculate the the value of all EvenChild elements javascript / php

Tags: javascript, php, nodes

I have this table, that holds 3 colums , name , price and remove button. 
What It needs is a way to calculate the sum of all even childs from the TR parent (every second TD since its the one that contains the price).

I am assuming Javascript will do that but im not sure how its gonna address Even or Odd elements.
I've also thought about using CSS to add some type of markers for the Even or Odd elements and use these markers to guide js but this is beyond my current knowledge.

I searched a lot for a solution to this, but to no avail..
Something along the lines of -

```
function count() {

var oddchildren = document.getElementByID('#order-table').childNodes.OddchildNodes;
var result = oddchildren + oddchildren;
}
```

I know this piece of code isnt even nearly proper, its just pseudo-code to represent the basic idea of what we need for the end result.

Here is the JS FIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/x8usjfs6/

Comment: Do a for loop iterating all Child nodes of the #order-table and use the n % 2 to check if the number is even and do your calculations accordingly.

Comment: How do I get the node index number?

Comment: Something among the lines of     var children = document.getElementByID('#order-table').childNodes;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  function calc() {
    // get the price elements
    let prices = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
    
    // turn them into an array and add up the prices
    let total = [].slice
      .call(prices)
      .reduce((prev, curr) => parseInt(curr.innerText) + prev, 0);
      
    // display the total
    document.querySelector('.total').innerHTML = total;
  }

  function remove(el) {
    // keep going up the tree until you find the row
    while (el.tagName !== "TR") {
      el = el.parentElement;
    }
    // remove the row
    el.remove();
  }

  // each time a button is clicked, remove a row and
  // recalculate the total
  function removeAndRecalc() {
    remove(this);
    calc();
  }
  
  // add click listeners to the remove buttons
  [].slice
    .call(document.querySelectorAll('.remove'))
    .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', removeAndRecalc));
    
  // calculate the total right off the bat
  calc();
});
```

```css
.price:before {
  content: '$'
}

.total:before {
  content: '$'
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Engineering Suit Level I</td>
      <td class="price">100</td>
      <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Engineering Suit Level I</td>
      <td class="price">100</td>
      <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Standart Plasma Cutter</td>
      <td class="price">120</td>
      <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Standart Plasma Cutter</td>
      <td class="price">120</td>
      <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td class="total"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow brother, thats some deep **** !
Thanks for sharing your time to build this, im gonna make sure to adapt to my code and make this work :)